# GDB Python API: Create hardware breakpoint object

Tags: python, debugging, gdb

The gdb python API defines the `gdb.BP_BREAKPOINT` flag to use when creating a `gdb.Breakpoint` object, but there doesn't seem to be a flag that allows a hardware breakpoint to be set? Am I missing something?

I'd like to create a `gdb.Breakpoint` object so that I can override the `stop` method and react to breakpoints as they're triggered. As far as I can tell, there isn't a way to do this otherwise.

Interestingly enough, if I set a breakpoint the 'normal' way (eg, `break *0x400123`), then `gdb.breakpoints()` returns an object. However, if I set a hardware breakpoint the same way (`hbreak *0x400123`), no objects are returned. This seems to indicate that the python API can't access/manipulate HW breakpoints directly?

Using GDB 8.3.50.20190824-30.fc31 on Fedora 31.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem recently. I found a hacky workaround to force gdb to use hardware breakpoints.

There's the gdb [`auto-hw` setting](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html#:%7E:text=set%20breakpoint%20auto%2Dhw%20on), that lets gdb decide whether to insert hardware or software breakpoints automatically. This setting should be on by default.

If gdb isn't able to set a software breakpoint because the memory region is not writable, it will insert a hardware breakpoint. You can define a non-writable memory region by issuing the [`mem` command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory-Region-Attributes.html).

`mem 0 0xffffffffffffffff ro`

And then your script can create all the breakpoints it wants :) (well, at least all the breakpoints the processor allows it to create)

After the breakpoints are inserted, you can go back to normal memory regions by doing `mem auto`.

[This issue](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19151) has been [recently solved](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=commit;h=325d39e4e09f0b7c8eec7e33ca93d0a9c82632ec). So we can expect it will be available in a future release of gdb :)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't found a way to do this using the `gdb.Breakpoint`, but I've got a workaround instead.

```
offset = 0x400123

gdb.execute("hbreak *" + hex(offset))

while True:
    gdb.execute("continue")
    value = int(gdb.parse_and_eval("$pc"))
    if value == offset:
        # respond to hardware breakpoint here
    else:
        # something else happened??
```

It's not perfect, but meets my current needs.